# I am uncertain of how to make a piece of code for installing steam give permission to changes

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, chrome-book

I've been trying to install steam through Linux to my Lenovo chromebook but every time i follow the codes i always end up running into this error. I don't know how to give permission and am really just looking to see if anyone can help guide me on what to do in this situation.

i used the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

and after preparing to set up steam it said:

```
Failed to write 'change' to '/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent': Permission denied
```

**Update:** I found a way around this problem and can move on.

Comment: Welcome, [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Also edit the title to actually describe the actual problem.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thank you for informing me and helping me fit the guidelines. I'll keep that in mind for any future usage of this stack exchange. If there's any other edits I need to make please inform me.

Comment: Use the format tools to format the text, in this case you can format the error and the command as code, the button is `{}`, or select the text and press `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome, it takes time to get used to how to properly ask a question. Remove the "Thank you"s and "Sorry...". Just ask the question. If you are going to add new information, don't do it in the comments, edit the question once again adding it.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact you're using `dpkg`, I assume you are using Debian, or some other distribution derived from it.

The virtual file `/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent` is created on loading the `uinput` kernel module. Since it's part of the `sysfs` virtual filesystem that is created dynamically based on the current run-time state of the kernel, any changes made to its permissions won't persist through a reboot.

Steam's need to access this file is probably related to hardware support: having access to the services of the `uinput` kernel module probably simplifies the support of things like some advanced game controller features and/or the various SteamVR-compatible Virtual Reality gear.

If you have none of those hardware devices, you can probably ignore this error message: it should not stop Steam from installing.

When you are logged in locally, the system will automatically add some group memberships to your user account: those groups memberships will grant you extra hardware access that remote users won't normally get. For example, locally logged-in user will normally get the `plugdev` group membership, to allow them to easily use most USB devices. That group would probably be appropriate for Steam's use case too. So, you might want to have group write access to `/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent` for the `plugdev` group added automatically each time the `uinput` module is loaded.

(This use of the `plugdev` group may be specific to Debian and its derivatives: if you are using some other distribution, you might need to figure out how it handles hardware access permissions to locally logged-in users and adapt the procedure to match.)

You could do it with a command like this (all in one line):

```
echo "install uinput /sbin/modprobe -i uinput; /bin/chgrp plugdev /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent; /bin/chmod g+w /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/uinput.conf
```

This command creates a file named `/etc/modprobe.d/uinput.conf` and writes into it a line of custom installation instructions for the `uinput`kernel module. Instead of just loading the module, it will *first* load the module as usual, then run the `chgrp` and `chmod` commands to adjust the permissions of the `/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent` file.

After this, you should unload the `uinput` kernel module and reload it, to verify the configuration works as expected:

```
sudo modprobe -r uinput
sudo modprobe uinput
```

Now, `ls -l /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent` should display a result like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root plugdev 4096 May  6 02:08 /sys/devices/virtual/misc/uinput/uevent
```

indicating that any user that belongs to the `plugdev` group (i.e. any user that has logged in locally) will now be able to both read from and write into this file.